# How can I call a function within a DRF view?

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework

I am using Djano REST Framework for constructing APIs .I want something like below

```
def addTwoNumber(a,b):
    return a+b

class MyView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        my_result=addTwoNumber(request.data.get('firstnum'),request.data.get('secondnum'))
        return Response(data={"my_return_data":my_result})
```

That is , I want a view that doesn't deals with the `queryset` &`serializer_class` attributes. Is it possible ? Can anyone help me ?

Comment: are you getting any error here?

Comment: yes, Its says should add `queryset ` and `serializer_class ` Attributes. But I don't want to deal with database

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why are you using `ModelViewSet`? Just use `APIView` http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/

```
# views.py
from rest_framework.views import APIView

def addTwoNumber(a,b):
    return a+b

class MyView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        my_result=addTwoNumber(request.data.get('firstnum'),request.data.get('secondnum'))
        return Response(data={"my_return_data":my_result})

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^myview/$', MyView.as_view()),
    ...
]
```